# STL::container, Polymorphism

Tags: c++, oop, stl

My OOP knowledge is a bit rusty...
and I try polymorphism 1st time with containers I think.

```
class car {
  public: std::string color;
  public: virtual void foo (void) = 0;
  public: virtual ~car (void){}

};

class truck : public car {
  public: int tonnage;
  public: virtual void foo (void) {}
};

// expect for subclasses of car
```

...

```
truck *t = new truck ();
t->color="white";
t->tonnage=32;

std::list <car *> lst;   // for any kind of car
lst.push_back (t);

printf ("\n1:    %s", typeid (t).name ());
printf ("\n2:    %s", typeid (lst.front()).name());
```

I expected to see

```
1:    P3van
2:    P3van
```

but it was

```
1:    P3van
2:    P3car
```

Is that not possible with containers or whats the problem?
I need to the the subclass out of it, not the parent. As far I read slicing is not the problem with pointers.
Thanks for help!

**EDIT1:**

I added virtual functions. But is is the same result.

**EDIT2:**

I'd like to downcast with the typid-info. Otherwise I can put a id-member into the base-class but I thought it would be possible (e.g. dynamic typecheck/cast).

Comment: In order to polymorphism reallly work, the base class have to contain at least one `virtual` function (which, in polymorphic context, should be at least `virtual` destructor).

Comment: Your classes aren't polymorphic. They are using the plain "is a" relationship of inheritance. For a set of classes to be polymorphic they need to have virtual member functions.

Comment: And the output is correct. The contents of the lists are pointer to `car`. Those pointers may be *downcasted* to pointers to `truck` though, if they really are pointers to `truck` instances.

Comment: Do you really think this has to do with "STL" containers? Have you tried without one?

Comment: typeid(*(lst.front()))

Comment: thankts, it was the *.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ defines a polymorphic class as a class which has at least one virtual function.  `typeid` doesn't do anything special unless its argument is a polymorphic class.  So first, add a virtual destructor to `car`:

```
class car {
  public:
    virtual ~car() {}
    std::string color;
};
```

Also, `typeid` does not act polymorphically on pointers, only on objects / references.  Try

```
printf ("\n1:    %s", typeid (*t).name ());
printf ("\n2:    %s", typeid (*lst.front()).name());
```

Answer (score 0):

typeid() is not a member function of class car. So polymorphism does not apply here. Instead of typeid(XXX).name(), call XXX->some_virtual_member_function(), and you will see what you were hoping for.

Alternatively, if it is not the type of the pointer you were looking for but the type of the object, you should call typeid on the objects not the pointers.

E.g. instead of typeid(t), call typeid(*t).

Comment: typeid if for dynamic type checking and so part of c++